# Vulkan: Why do we need to check for window resize after VkQueuePresentKHR

Tags: vulkan

I am following the vulkan tutorial, currently at the part of swap chain recreation.

https://vulkan-tutorial.com/Drawing_a_triangle/Swap_chain_recreation

We are supposed to handle resizing explicitly by setting a boolean variable framebufferResized to true whether the window resize callback method is called. Then if the window has resized, we recreate the swap chain in the drawFrame method that is called every frame. Something like below.

```
VkResult result = vkAcquireNextImageKHR(device, swapChain, UINT64_MAX, imageAvailableSemaphores[currentFrame], VK_NULL_HANDLE, &imageIndex);
...
result = vkQueuePresentKHR(presentQueue, &presentInfo);
if (result == VK_ERROR_OUT_OF_DATE_KHR || result == VK_SUBOPTIMAL_KHR || framebufferResized) {
    framebufferResized = false;
    recreateSwapChain();
}
```

This is the statement I am confused about in the tutorial: "It is important to do this after vkQueuePresentKHR to ensure that the semaphores are in a consistent state, otherwise a signalled semaphore may never be properly waited upon." The "this" I am assuming is the check for the boolean framebufferResized and the subsequent recreateSwapChain(). The semaphores are just the semaphores to ensure that we acquire an image successfully before drawing to it, then drawing to it successfully before presenting it. It therefore makes no sense to me what the author is talking about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presumably, the "signal" refers to the `vkAcquire` and the swapchain recreation is protected by something like `vkDeviceWaitIdle`. And presumably, the author is worried about `VK_SUBOPTIMAL`, and wants to recreate the swapchain in that case.

But `vkDeviceWaitIdle` does not cover the pending semaphore from `vkAcquire`, as confirmed here: https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-Docs/issues/1059.

This means the semaphore has to be first waited on by a `vkQueueSubmit`. Only then can the semaphore be caught by a `vk*WaitIdle` command, and only after that destroyed in a valid way.